# Android - Pause music player when a video is started

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I have and app with an audio player and video player. I want when the audio player is playing in background and I start the video, the audio player to stop itself.

I could achieve this easily with a broadcast receiver by sending an intent when opening the Video, and listen for that intent in Audio player and stop it in onReceive().

However, I would like to extend this feature not only to my audio player, but to all audio players. So I thought if there's a standard intent to send when the video player opens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **audio focus** for this. Cf the RandomMusicPlayer sample android project:

```
public class AudioFocusHelper {
    AudioManager mAM;
    MusicFocusable mFocusable;

    private final AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener listener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        /** 
         * Called by AudioManager on audio focus changes. We implement this by calling our
         * MusicFocusable appropriately to relay the message.
         */
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
            if (mFocusable == null) return;
            switch (focusChange) {
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                    mFocusable.onGainedAudioFocus();
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                    mFocusable.onLostAudioFocus(false);
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                    mFocusable.onLostAudioFocus(true);
                    break;
                 default:
            }
        }
    };;

    public AudioFocusHelper(Context ctx, MusicFocusable focusable) {
        mAM = (AudioManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mFocusable = focusable;
    }

    /** Requests audio focus. Returns whether request was successful or not. */
    public boolean requestFocus() {
        return AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED ==
            mAM.requestAudioFocus(listener, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
    }

    /** Abandons audio focus. Returns whether request was successful or not. */
    public boolean abandonFocus() {
        return AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED == mAM.abandonAudioFocus(listener);
    }
}
```